# Creating searchable groups with dropdown?

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have a dropdown with search functionality. I'd like to be able to search "Category" for example, and see objects that I designate to said category. Currently everything is hidden (except the category you search for) if there are no results, unless the group/category name is included in the `<li>`.

My code ([here is the JSFiddle which loads cleaner, for some reason](http://jsfiddle.net/code4ever/k4fLL8d6/13/)):

```js
$("#search-criteria").on("keyup", function() {
  var g = $(this).val().toLowerCase();
  $(".dropdown-item").each(function() {
    var s = $(this).text().toLowerCase();
    $(this).closest('.dropdown-item')[s.indexOf(g) !== -1 ? 'show' : 'hide']();
  });
});
```

```css
.search-box {
  margin: 10px;
}

.scrollable-menu {
  height: auto;
  max-height: 500px;
  overflow-x: hidden;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.2.1.slim.min.js" integrity="sha384-KJ3o2DKtIkvYIK3UENzmM7KCkRr/rE9/Qpg6aAZGJwFDMVNA/GpGFF93hXpG5KkN" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>

<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/popper.js/1.12.9/umd/popper.min.js"></script>

<link href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.0.0/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
<script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.0.0/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>

<div class="dropdown">
  <button class="btn btn-secondary" type="button" id="dropdownMenuButton" data-toggle="dropdown" aria-haspopup="true" aria-expanded="false">
    Components
  </button>
  <div class="dropdown-menu scrollable-menu" aria-labelledby="dropdownMenuButton">
    <li class="row search-box">
      <input class="form-control search" id="search-criteria" type="text" placeholder="Search components" />
    </li>
    <a class="dropdown-item" href="#">Component 1</a>
    <a class="dropdown-item" href="#">Component 2</a>
    <a class="dropdown-item" href="#">Component 3</a>
    <h6 class="dropdown-header dropdown-item">Category</h6>
    <a class="dropdown-item" href="#">Component In C</a>
    <a class="dropdown-item" href="#">Component 2 In C</a>
    <h6 class="dropdown-header dropdown-item">Category 2</h6>
    <a class="dropdown-item" href="#">Component In C2</a>
    <a class="dropdown-item" href="#">Component 2 In C2</a>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: what exactly is the problem? you don't know how to hide the header? `$(".dropdown").find("h6").hide();`

Comment: No, I'd like to be able to search for the header (in this case, Category) and see the links under it. Currently you only see the header

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I wound up adding a span with the category name to each of my child items. Kind of round about and I'd love to see what others can come up with that's better, but for now [this new code works](http://jsfiddle.net/code4ever/k4fLL8d6/31/). Try typing test in to see what I mean.

Old Code:

```js
$("#search-criteria").on("keyup", function() {
  var g = $(this).val().toLowerCase();
  $(".dropdown-item").each(function() {
    var s = $(this).text().toLowerCase();
    $(this).closest('.dropdown-item')[s.indexOf(g) !== -1 ? 'show' : 'hide']();
  });
});
```

```css
.search-box {
  margin: 10px;
}

.scrollable-menu {
  height: auto;
  max-height: 500px;
  overflow-x: hidden;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.2.1.slim.min.js" integrity="sha384-KJ3o2DKtIkvYIK3UENzmM7KCkRr/rE9/Qpg6aAZGJwFDMVNA/GpGFF93hXpG5KkN" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>

<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/popper.js/1.12.9/umd/popper.min.js"></script>

<link href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.0.0/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
<script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.0.0/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>

<div class="dropdown">
  <button class="btn btn-secondary" type="button" id="dropdownMenuButton" data-toggle="dropdown" aria-haspopup="true" aria-expanded="false">
    Components
  </button>
  <div class="dropdown-menu scrollable-menu" aria-labelledby="dropdownMenuButton">
    <li class="row search-box">
      <input class="form-control search" id="search-criteria" type="text" placeholder="Search components" />
    </li>
    <a class="dropdown-item" href="#">Component 1</a>
    <a class="dropdown-item" href="#">Component 2</a>
    <a class="dropdown-item" href="#">Component 3</a>
    <h6 class="dropdown-header dropdown-item">Category</h6>
    <a class="dropdown-item" href="#">Component In C</a>
    <a class="dropdown-item" href="#">Component 2 In C</a>
    <h6 class="dropdown-header dropdown-item">Category 2</h6>
    <a class="dropdown-item" href="#">Component In C2</a>
    <a class="dropdown-item" href="#">Component 2 In C2</a>
  </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

Separate everything out more, have each header in it's own section and nest the items underneath that. Then when you have scope on search where this refers to the desired h6, you can hide/show all children elements of that by class,

```
 $(this).children('.dropdown-item').show();
```

or something similar.